# Filter with Linq comma separated field

Tags: linq

I have a table with a field called COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUES. How can I filter with a single! (I have to integrate it into a larger query) LINQ query
all rows, where one of the entries is in a range of integer.

```
Table TEST
ID          COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUES
-----------------------------------
1           '1,2,3,4'
2           '1,5,100,4,33'
3           '666,999'
4           '5,55,5'
```

Filter for Range "10 - 99" would result in

```
ID
------------------------
2           (because of 33)
4           (because of 55)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are aware of the performance side effect of calling `AsEnumerable()` method and it doesn't harm:

```
int lowerBound = 10;  // lower bound of your range
int upperBound = 99;  // upper bound of your range

var d = from row in context.Test.AsEnumerable()
        let integers = row.COMMA_SEPERATED_VALUES
                          .Split(new char[] { ',' })
                          .Select(p => int.Parse(p))
        where integers.Any(p => p < upperBound && p > lowerBound)
        select row;
```

Comment: Cool. I thought that was probably the problem but thought it best to let you fix. ;-)